# List icon vs menu icon

Tags: icons, android

As of Ice Cream Sandwich, the [new standard icon for menus](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) is three vertically aligned squares as such:

[image: ICS menu icon example]

Before that, the menu expansion was three horizontal lines like this, but without the triangle:

[image]

Annoyingly enough, that icon (again, without the triangle) looks a lot like a list. In fact it looks so much like it that I have a hard time picking something else to signify a list view of something.

Even Google's own Roman Nurik has used that icon for a list (pre-ICS):

[image]

But yet it's not consistent or clear that it is not the menu icon. I have gotten feedback from multiple long-time Android users that the list view looks like a menu icon to them. Even worse, Facebook still uses the list to mean menu:

[image]

And Chrome on OS X uses it to mean menu as well (Jelly Bean Android uses the three squares):

[image]

So my question is this:

What is the correct (according to Google) and consistent icon to indicate a list view as of the latest Google OS?

Is confusion from users to be expected and should we just deal with it until pre-ICS users die off and everyone is on board with the new icon set?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but could it be 'overflow menu' is a different icon than 'menu' itself? The overflow appears to be vertical elipses (as silly as that may sound...)

Comment: @DA01 What do you mean?

Comment: I mean it seems that they are two different things. "Menu overflow" and "Menu". So maybe it makes sense to have them different. Just my interpretation.

Comment: The overflow icon represents "action overflow" and is very different from the concept of a menu. It represents additional actions that are either off-screen intentionally or due to lack of space. The point above about it representing a vertical ellipsis is spot on.

Comment: @RomanNurik and DA01 : Ah! Okay. I had no mental blueprint for an action overflow. It's not something I have consciously come across before. The distinction between that and menu makes sense now though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Google's Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20120814.zip) ([link taken from this page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)) includes a special icon specifically for this purpose (the icon name is `4-collections-view-as-list.png`):

[image: Android View As List icon]

The three-dots symbol you list is called `ic_action_overflow.png` (corroborating DA01's comment that the symbol means *overflow*—as in 'more…'—not necessarily *menu*).

Android's convention for menus is the arrow you mentioned in the question, and apps are really taking to the sort of thing your Facebook example uses. In fact Google have added the same exact control to its mobile website:

[image: Google's mobile website demonstrating the menu icon]
*Image from [Search Engine Roundtable](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-mobile-black-navigation-15821.html)*

[There's a StackOverflow question about those kinds of menus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11377472/181495) with some interesting examples too.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using an icon like [this one from GLYPHICONS](http://glyphicons.com/):

[image]

It is likely that users would find it intuitive because we have been using unordered lists for so long.