# What is the best way you have seen to represent something is draggable?

Tags: gui-design, affordance, drag-n-drop

I've seen many different ways to represent an object on a page as being draggable, but I was the most effective way in your experience of doing so?

Comment: Duplicate: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-to-visualize-the-possibility-of-dragndrop, http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34158/how-to-make-it-obvious-that-you-can-drag-things-that-you-normally-cant

Answer (score 0):

There are many good ways of doing this, but the best ones provide an affordance like a handle, sometimes indicated by a grid of dots or rule lines, along with the cursor change to a hand. See the example from GMail, but note that the way it works in GMail is not draggable; it is used to indicate "Move This". I'm including the image because I like the affordance, despite the fact that the implementation is not straight-up drag-and-drop.

The second example is from Edx.org, for a course called Energy 101. The instructions say "drag each tile to rank industries..." and the handle is composed of horizontal rule lines. The cursor also changes to a hand on mouseover.

[image: GMail's pointing hand and handle made of dots]

[image: Edx example of drag and drop]